# Could not find method repositories() for arguments on settings ‘MyApplicationExample' of type org.gradle.initialization.DefaultSettings

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I have a custom android library, and an application to demonstrate the use of this library in the same repository. Gradle project sync fails with the error in the title of the question. In the app/build.gradle I'm compiling the library project with..

```
    dependencies {
    compile project ":react-native-my-library" // <--- this is where it fails
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

In the MainApplication.java in getPackages I've added the lib..

```
new MainReactPackage(),
new RNMyLibraryPackage());
```

and in android/settings.gradle...

```
include ':react-native-my-library'
project(':react-native-my-library').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,   '../node_modules/react-native-my-library/android')
```

From what I've been able to find the gradle sync error is due to not correctly finding the library.

Extra Log:

> Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown property ':react-native-my-library' for DefaultProjectDependency{dependencyProject='project ':app'', configuration='default'} of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultProjectDependency.
>   2017-10-25 13:43:33,510 [16025306]   WARN - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask -
>   2017-10-25 13:43:33,510 [16025306]   INFO - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask - Could not get unknown property ':react-native-my-library' for DefaultProjectDependency{dependencyProject='project ':app'', configuration='default'} of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultProjectDependency.
>   Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
>   2017-10-25 13:43:33,510 [16025306]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Sync with Gradle for project 'LibraryExample' failed: Could not get unknown property ':react-native-my-library' for DefaultProjectDependency{dependencyProject='project ':app'', configuration='default'} of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultProjectDependency.

Comment: can you put the log plz

Comment: @Fakher Done...

Comment: try to import it using IDE. file->New->Import module->set the path of your library project and a name than call it by the name you set ":libName"

Comment: @Fakher I did this and more or less it worked. If you can answer this question as an answer and not a comment I can mark it as the correct answer. Thanks for taking the time to answer my Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to import your library using IDE:
**New**->**File**->**Import Module**->Set the path of your library project and a name than call it by the name you set ":libName"